# DirtyPropertyNames method in beforeUpdate only returns version

Tags: grails, beforeupdate

I'm having a problem with using the dirtyPropertyNames method.

I'm using grails version 2.1.3.
The method below always prints version and none of the other changed String properties.

Anybody familiar with this problem?

```
@Override
def beforeUpdate() {
    def names = this.dirtyPropertyNames
    println "dirty names: ${names}"
    for (name in names) {
        println "original value: ${this.getPersistentValue(name)}"
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you update/save your data? Please give some more details...

Comment: I'm saving the data by using save(flush: true)

Comment: Some more details? :-)